# A value is missing from a PHP associative array with mixed keys

Tags: php, arrays

While studying PHP arrays I have come upon a rather curios example:

```
<?php
$example = array(
        "1"=>"A", 1=>"B", "C", 2=>"D"
);
var_dump($example);
?>
```

I was expecting this piece of code to display three values: B, C and D. Instead, only B and D are printed:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "D"
}
```

I understand that A is replaced by B because the key (string)"1" is actually being cast to (int) 1.

I know that integer keys are created by adding 1 to the last defined integer key of an array. Is the value C replaced by D because when the array is created, the next possible integer key to be assigned to C is 1+1 = 2 ?

Comment: Your sample output doesn't match your input.

Comment: Ah, sorry, Evert. I have updated the output to reflect the input.

Comment: `C` is assigned to index `2`, correct.

Comment: Related: [Why PHP lose item value of array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42204262/2943403) and [How does PHP set keys for arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15385070/2943403)

Comment: And [How to avoid the previous values in php array overridden by the later ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37084125/2943403)

Answer (score 2):

Exactly so. You can test it by assigning D (by the way, remember the quotes) to a different key:

```
<?php 
    $example = [ "A", "B", 1 => "C" ];
    print_r($example);

<?php
    $example = [ "1" => "A", "1" => "B", "C", 3 => "D" ]; 
    print_r($example);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => C
)
Array
(
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not have quotes and numbers correctly.
Try this:

```
<?php
$example = array(
        "1"=>"A", "1"=>"B", "2"=>"C", "3"=>"D"
);

var_dump($example);
?>
```